# How do I deal with whitespace when comparing console strings to other strings?

Tags: java, string, console, whitespace

In Java programming; I have an array of many strings that are sentences (ex. `String[] compString = "This is a sentence"`), of course including whitespace. I want the user to type in the same sentence into the console, and I want the program to compare both strings and tell the user if they repeated the sentence properly or not. Meaning, I want the user to type in "This is a sentence" and the program will compare `userString` to `compString` here and output "Correct". But, due to the whitespace in the user's string, it returns "Wrong" because it's only comparing "This" to the computer's string "This is a sentence". I tried fixing it with this:

```
if(userString.replace(" ","").equalsIgnoreCase(compString[0].replace(" ",""))){
```

But this does not help and still only compares "This" to "This is a sentence". Did I type the code properly to eliminate all whitespace? Or is there a different way I can do this?

Comment: Please show the code which reads the input - are you using a `Scanner`? Did you use `nextLine()`? Did you strip the trailing newline?

Comment: String[] compString = "This is a sentence"; // you cannot assign a String to an array of Strings...

Comment: I tried "nextLine" and it completely eliminates the console and just outputs "Wrong". Sorry for the confusion; the examples I gave above will not match the actual code (I was trying to keep it simple), but I'll add in more of the code to the OP, in a second here..

Comment: You might want to read [mcve]

Comment: It won't let me post the code, even though I keep reformatting it... I, don't quite know what to do, here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to assign your array correct way something like bellow:

```
String[] compString = {"This is a sentence"};
```

And then try to compare ignoring consequtive whitespace and case-sensitivity  one approach could be

```
String[] compString = {"This is a sentence"};
String userString = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

boolean isSame = userString.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(compString[0].trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));

System.out.println(isSame);
```

Comment: I can write an array (I was shortening things for the example), but my problem is comparing a sentence from the CONSOLE to a sentence that's in the array.

Comment: @Ray25Lee did you check my modification?

Answer (score 0):

Considering **compString** is your string and **userString** is the one provided by user, following comparison should work:

```
compString.replaceAll(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(userString.replaceAll(" ", ""))
```

Comment: ``th is is a sen ten ce`` and ``this is a sentence`` are same as your code